# mongodb array matching

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How do I accomplish the following?

```
db.test.save( {a: [1,2,3]} );

db.test.find( {a: [1,2,3,4]} );  //must match because it contains all required values [1, 2, 3]
db.test.find( {a: [1,2]} );  //must NOT match because the required value 3 is missing
```

I know about $in and $all but they work differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting..The problem is..the $in and the $or operators get applied on the elements of the array that you are comparing *against* each document in the collection, not on the elements of the arrays in the documents..To summarize your question: You want it to be a match, if any of the documents in the collection happens to be a *subset* of the passed array. I can't think of a way to do this unless you swap your input and output. What I mean is..Let's take your first input:

`db.test.find( {a: [1,2,3,4]} );`

Consider putting this in a temporary collection say,temp as:

`db.temp.save( {a: [1,2,3,4]} );`
Now iterate over each document in test collection and 'find' it in temp, with the $all operator to ensure it is completely contained, i.e., do something like this:

`foreach(doc in test)

{ 
db.temp.find( { a: { $all: doc.a } } );
}`

This is definitely a workaround! I am not sure if I am missing any other operator that can do this job.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no operator that will find documents with a subset values. There is a proposed improvement to add a $subset operator.  Please feel free to up vote the issue in JIRA:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-974

Other potential workarounds, which may not be suitable for your use case, may involve map reduce or the new aggregation framework (available in MongoDB version 2.2):
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_project