# MongoDB - select document where all values in field array are present in a given array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

I have documents like

```
{
    foo : [1, 2]
}
{
    foo : [2, 3]
}
```

Given an array like

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

How would I select only the second document? i.e. select only the documents where all the values in foo match values in a given array.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are some ways to match array. There is no exact solution for your need.

Considering you have documents like :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b05a712961f4704684d901"), "x" : [ 6, 7, 8, 9 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b05a712961f4704684d902"), "x" : [ 7, 8, 9, 10 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b05a712961f4704684d903"), "x" : [ 8, 9, 10, 11 ] }
```

You can use query1 like:

```
db.collection.find({x:[3,4,5,6]})
```

The result is exact match only for arrays like x

result1:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b05a712961f4704684d8fe"), "x" : [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ] }
```

query1 will not match :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b05a712961f4704684d8fe"), "x" : [ 3, 4, 5] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b05a712961f4704684d8fe"), "x" : [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] }
```

You can use : query2 like:

```
db.t.find({x:{$all:[3,4]}})
```

result2 can be:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b05a722961f4704684daf1"), "x" : [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b05c332961f4704684dce4"), "x" : [ 3, 4, 5 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b05c772961f4704684dce5"), "x" : [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ] }
```

You can use : query3 like:

```
 db.t.find({x:{$in:[3,4]}})
```

Result3  would look like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b05a722961f4704684daf1"), "x" : [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b05a722961f4704684daf2"), "x" : [ 4, 5, 6, 7 ] }
```

See this question also : [mongodb array matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647274/mongodb-array-matching)

So there is an open/unresolved ticket for a $subset operator which does what you likely to.